# Android - Location Listener NETWORK_PROVIDER

Tags: android, locationmanager, locationlistener, android-gps

I am using a `LocationListener` in my application, and I assigned two providers to it (`GPS_PROVIDER` and `NETWORK_PROVIDER`) and this listener has four callbacks (`onLocationChanged`, `onStatusChanged`, `onProviderEnabled` and `onProviderDisabled`).

I have no problem with the GPS since when I turn it off or on the `onProviderEnabled` and `onProviderDisabled` callbacks work. The problem is when I change my WIFI state, these callbacks are not called.

I found some information about it, and created a method to decide if there is internet or not in the device, the problem is that if I have internet, I assign the `NETWORK_PROVIDER` and then I switch off my wifi the callbacks are eventually not called, and then I cannot manage this.

What should I do, to configure the network provider correctly?

**Code:**

Assigning the providers:

```
  isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(GPS_PROVIDER);
  isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(NETWORK_PROVIDER) && isNetworkAvailable();

  if(!isGpsEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
    this.gpsAware.onGpsError("Your Gps providers are not available");
    throw new Exception("Verify your GPS or Network connection");
  } else {
    if(isNetworkEnabled)
      addProvider(NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(isGpsEnabled)
      addProvider(GPS_PROVIDER);
```

The addProvider method:

```
private void addProvider(String provider) {
    //Check permissions
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
        provider,
        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
}
```

Comment: Why not use GoogleApi location services and take advantage of the new fused location and SettingsApi https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html

Comment: I just read about, but I am wondering if there is not problem with the offline usage. This app must use the GPS when is offline.